# Are 'what cards can I get that do X' questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are questions that ask for cards that do [thing] on topic? I feel like this is probably a list question and therefore off-topic, but I figured I'd check before leaving.

Ex: In MTG, what cards let me have infinite hand size/scry 5 or more/make X tokens/other function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, those questions are allowed. This kind of question is different from "list questions" because the possible answers are drawn from a specific known list, so it is possible to verify that an answer is comprehensive.

Comment: Related, "list questions" is commonly misunderstood by our modern usage. They are not questions that will likely receive an answer containing a bulleted list. Instead, they are unbounded discussiony questions that result in an endless list of answers where we can't consider any to be better or more correct. We figured out better verbiage for these questions in 2010-ish, but the "list questions" shorthand stuck around for some reason. They're covered in our "don't ask" guidelines nowadays and fall into one or more of our close reasons.